# How to sort asc and desc with list.js

Tags: jquery, html, listjs

I'm using list.js to build a search and sort option with dropdown select options,
Here is my working code:

JS:

```
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name' ]
};
var myList = new List('mylist', options);

$('select.sort').change(function(){
  var selection = $(this).val();
  myList.sort(selection);
});
```

HTML

```
<select class="sort">
    <option value="" selected>Sort by</option>
    <option value="name">Sort by Name</option>
</select>
```

Now i'm trying to sort 'name' with ASC and DESC, for example -

```
<select class="sort">
    <option value="" selected>Sort by</option>
    <option value="name">Name ASC</option>
    <option value="name">Name DESC</option>
</select>
```

I found this on the docs,

```
listObj.sort('name', { order: "asc" });
listObj.sort('name', { order: "desc" });
```

But I don't understand how to do this with above dropdown. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
$('.sort').on('change', function() {
   var col = $('.sort.column').val();
   var dir = $('.sort.direction').val();
   if ( col !== "" && dir != "" )
   {
       myList.sort(col, { order: dir });
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="sort column">
    <option value="" selected>Sort by</option>
    <option value="name">Sort by Name</option>
</select>
<select class="sort direction">
    <option value="" selected>Sort by</option>
    <option value="asc">ASC</option>
    <option value="desc">DESC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It allows with only one option. If I have more options like 'Name ASC, Name DESC, Date ASC, Date DESC' it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @FrankerZ!

In vanilla JS with 1 pulldown.

```
  <select id="sort">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="name" sort="asc">Name ascending</option>
        <option value="name" sort="desc">Name descending</option>
        <option value="born" sort="asc">Born ascending</option>
  </select>
```

```
    var sort    = document.querySelector("#sort"); 
    sort.addEventListener("change", sortBySelect, false); 

    function sortBySelect(event) {
        selected = event.target.selectedOptions[0];
        sort = selected.attributes.value.value;
        dir = selected.attributes.sort.value;
        userList.sort(sort, { order: dir });
    }
```

Note: I am just a novice in JavaScript. So if you see any improvements possible then feel free to respond.